# Kafka Consumer left consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I've faced some problem using Kafka. Any help is much appreciated!
I have zookeeper and kafka cluster 3 nodes each in docker swarm. Kafka broker configuration you can see below.

```
  KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
  KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
  KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS: 2
  KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 8
  KAFKA_REPLICA_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS: 30000
  KAFKA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS: 30000
  KAFKA_COMPRESSION_TYPE: "gzip"
  KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS: "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"
  KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: "-Xmx768m -Xms768m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m"
```

My case:

- 20x Producers producing messages to kafka topic constantly
- 1x Consumer reads and log messages
- Kill kafka node (docker container stop) so now cluster has 2 nodes of Kafka broker (3rd will start and join cluster automatically)
- And Consumer not consuming messages anymore because it left consumer group due to rebalancing

Does exist any mechanism to tell consumer to join group after rebalancing?

Logs:

```
 INFO 1 --- [ | loggingGroup] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-0, groupId=loggingGroup] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
 WARN 1 --- [ | loggingGroup] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-0, groupId=loggingGroup] This member will leave the group because consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

Comment: Increase max.poll.interval.ms value. As you can't poll during rebalancing, your last heartbeat is greater than the interval value, so the cluster thinks you're dead and will kick you out. These are my two cents..

Comment: But how to guess correct interval? Always can be such situation when I'll need to increase it more.

Comment: Then increase it to a very high value. There is no impact for the process during "normal execution". At least, increase it to the maximum time a rebalance operation takes. But as I said, that was just a guess... maybe your problem comes from other side

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Answer (score 0):

@Rostyslav Whenever we make a call by consumer to read a message, it does 2 major calls.

1. Poll
2. Commit

Poll is basically fetching records from kafka topic and commit tells kafka to save it as a read message , so that it's not read again. While polling few parameters play major role:

1. max_poll_records
2. max_poll_interval_ms

FYI: variable names are per python api.

Hence, whenever we try to read message from Consumer, it makes a poll call every max_poll_interval_ms and the same call is made only after the records fetched (as defined in max_poll_records) are processed. So, whenever, max_poll_records are not processed in max_poll_inetrval_ms, we get the error.

In order to overcome this issue, we need to alter one of the two variable. Altering max_poll_interval_ms ccan be hectic as sometime it may take longer time to process certain records, sometime lesser records. I always advice to play with max_poll_records as a fix to the issue. This works for me.